# How do screenshot blocking technologies work?

Tags: windows, chrome, drm

I've noticed I can't take screenshots of videos in Star+. When I paste whatever I tried to shot, it comes all black (subtitles however are visible). After some research, I found out it happens with other streaming services as well. It looks like some DRM technology to avoid copyright infringement.

Since the video is presented on a browser, I'm not sure how these technologies work. Does anybody know?

Comment: duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175756/how-does-netflix-prevent-users-from-taking-screenshots-of-chrome-browser

Comment: @foreverska yes, it's the same question, although it doesn't feel like a proper SO question to me. Besides, the question is not properly answered there (as pointed out by a commenter). They simply cited the technologies behind the feature, never explaining things like how the right image pixels are detected, how the browser intercepts the Print Screen key, etc. This is what I expect as an answer here.

Comment: I believe some of this is at the OS level.  To get around it, run inside a virtual machine, and take the screenshot from the OS hosting the virtual machine.

Comment: Since this is not a question about security, then the SO should stand and perhaps get more attention. Your question is "how does Encrypted Media Extensions work?" and the links in the SO answer point you to the definitive and authoritative documents.

Comment: @schroeder understood. To make things clearer, could you please explain why there's a [drm] tag on this stack?

Comment: Sure, for when DRM becomes a security concern.

Comment: @schroeder I learned there are some ways to circumvent DRM to allow screenshots. Changing the question to "how does X bypass DRM" would turn this question on-topic?